# How to translate "there is only one left"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I want to say something like

> There is only one cookie left.

I'm thinking it would be something like

> Es gibt nur eine Kekse.

but how do I convey the meaning that the rest were eaten?

Comment: [Google Translate](https://translate.google.de/#en/de/There%20is%20only%20one%20cookie%20left.) is quite good in this case.

Comment: @PerlDuck Except for "Cookie"...

Comment: @Matthias True, that should be „Keks“. But GT this time really did a good job. The keywords are „nur noch“ (only one) and „übrig“ (left). But to my understanding translation requests are not particularly welcome here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this context "left" is translated as "übrig"

> Es ist nur noch ein Keks übrig

Comment: +1, and one could also write *Es ist nur noch ein Keks **da**.*

Comment: *...ein Keks da* is more colloquial